# App freezes but CPU usage increases over time

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xcode-instruments

I've been stuck on this thing for many hours now and I don't know what else to search for.

There's not much I can provide since the debugger doesn't show any errors but it's reproducible--I tap on a very specific item in a table view, the act of which should dismiss that modal, and then my app freezes. That doesn't happen for the other items in the table view--the modal dismisses perfectly and the app goes on.

I checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10196439/855680) suspecting that it's a deadlock, however:

- Everytime I hit the pause button in the debugger, the main thread is up to something different.
- The CPU usage as seen from Xcode's Debug navigator increases over time.
- I put breakpoints at one of my custom UIControl's `layoutSubviews` method and it keeps getting called. It does not call `[super layoutSubviews]`, does not call `setNeedsLayout` on anyone, and simply sets the frames of its subviews because I'm not using Autolayout.

How can I debug this thing? I've been looking around Xcode Instruments but I can't make sense of the data I'm seeing. The System Trace template, specifically, seems capable of stopping right when the freeze occurs, unlike the others which keep on recording.

Added: What I see in System Trace [image: What I see in System Trace]

Comment: Did you check for recursive method calling after tapping on that cell. Add some code

Comment: Can you confirm you're not manipulating UI from a background thread? didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not called on the main thread in all circumstances (http://stackoverflow.com/a/22173707/80678)

Comment: @kenleycapps Nope, didSelectRowAtIndexPath isn't running in a background thread. It's running on the main thread, no dispatch_asyncs in there.

Comment: The time profiler instrument will probably be more useful.  Select "invert call tree" and "hide system libraries" and see what it shows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Paulw11's comment helped--the Time Profiler template is better suited for this task than the System Trace instrument.

I used the Time Profiler and got led to a bunch of traces that point to the UINavigationBar as the suspect repetitive caller to my custom UIControl's `layoutSubviews`. To further explain my view hierarchy:

- My "Home" view controller has a custom title view in its UINavigationItem
- The custom title view is a custom UIControl that launches a modal when tapped

Here's the deal: If I `alloc-initWithFrame` my custom `UIControl` with a frame of `CGRectZero`, the app freezes. If I provide a garbage initial value to the frame (which is disregarded anyway since UINavigationBar reshapes my custom UIControl) like `CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)`, **the crash doesn't happen**.

I'm guessing that UINavigationBar gets confused about how to layout a custom title view that has an initial frame of `(0, 0, 0, 0)`. Sounds like an Apple bug.

*Note: I'm running on iOS 8.2.*

Answer (score 2):

Instruments is the tool you want to diagnose the issue. Try inspecting your app with `Time Profiler`, performing the task that you were observing to increase CPU usage and then analyze the results, checking `Invert Call Tree` and `Hide System Libraries`. You can also set time markers if there is a specific time period you are looking to inspect. From here, you can see what calls are sucking up the CPU.