# How can I debug iOS app freeze if the pause button does not provide any information?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, profiling, freeze

I am facing app freezing issue that is not getting detected in exception breakpoints. All my UI related code runs on main thread. As suggested in the question [My app freezes but no error appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196344/my-app-freezes-but-no-error-appears), I tapped on the pause button to check error, but cannot figure out anything from it. Please help me understand better. Attaching the screenshot of my xcode screen here:

[image]

Comment: Eventually check the other threads, especially the ConnectionLoader one, or put a breakpoint on exceptions. Also, check code around the issue, isolate it.

Comment: Cannot figure out just anything from it. A queue i can give is that the freeze occurs when one view controller pops out and the below view controller is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

When your app freeze.. try the following and resolve it

In Xcode(8 or Higher)

1. Analyze Code - Command+Shift+B
2. [Enable Address Sanitizier in Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/code_diagnostics/address_sanitizer/enabling_the_address_sanitizer?language=objc)
3. [Memory Graph](https://medium.com/zendesk-engineering/ios-identifying-memory-leaks-using-the-xcode-memory-graph-debugger-e84f097b9d15)

**Thread Sanitizer and Static Analysis**

Xcode makes it easier to find several new categories of bugs with improvements in Runtime Sanitization and the Clang Static Analyzer. The Thread Sanitizer will help you find data races and other concurrency bugs. The static analyzer has been extended to search for localizability issues, check nullability, and find memory leaks in MRR code.

1. Edit Scheme – Diagnostics tab
2. “Enable Thread Sanitizer” checkbox
3. Build and Run
4. View all of the generated runtime issues
5. Can choose to break on every issue